# При переносе проекта из Eclipse в Android Studio пропали все .java файлы

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, android

При переносе проекта из Eclipse в Android Studio пропали все .java файлы! Остались только файлы, которые лежали в `values` и файл манифеста. Можно их как-то восстановить или проекту конец?

Comment: Они пропали физически? Пропали из файловой системы?

Comment: @LEQADA, да... :(

Comment: Попробуйте восстановители файлов использовать какие-то (Recuva f.e.). Наверное, это хороший пример того, почему нужно пользоваться Git.

Comment: @LEQADA, не помогает... А что такое ``Git``?

Comment: Git это [система управления версиями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8). Существует много таких систем, но Git самая популярная.

Answer (score 2):

То, что при импорте файлы были физически удалены - звучит маловероятно. В *Android Studio* другая структура каталогов проекта - с большой долей вероятности они находятся теперь в другой папке.

Comment: Искал через поисковик Windows — не нашел.